# Can´t locate libgsl.so.23 even though installed

Tags: 16.04, dependencies, libraries

I am trying to run molflow on my computer (ubuntu 16.04.5 unity DE) and I have installed all the dependencies that are required. Even so when trying to start the program I get the following error:

```
user@computer:~/molflow_linux_debian_2.7.3$ ./molflow 
./molflow: error while loading shared libraries: libgsl.so.23: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have looked into the available packages using apt-get and I have tried looking for it online but I can´t seem to find where to get this library. Help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you install the dependencies? if you installed `libgsl2` from the 16.04 repository, it will only provide `libgsl.so.19` I think (`libgsl.so.23` is the default on 18.04)

Comment: I used apt-get to install the dependencies.

It seemed that installing the 32bit version of libsdl2 worked. It is now looking for libSDL2-2.0.so.0 still

Comment: Okay. I´ll see if I can find the source somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: If installing the 32 bit version solved the issue then please ignore my comment about installing a newer version. (I actually wondered whether 32/64 bit was the issue but didn't see anything on the molflow page indicating that it was a 32-bit application)

Comment: It solved the issue for one library but not for another one. Compiling from source was a success only I have to find out how to link to it now.

Answer (score 2):

I installed gsl-2.5 from [GNU FTP site](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gsl/) on Ubuntu 14.04 and encountered the same error.  `libgsl.so.23` is installed by default under the path of `/usr/local/lib`.  But the operating system could not be able to locate the file at runtime.

I solved the problem with `sudo ldconfig` command according to the suggestion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux).

[gsl documentation site](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/usage.html#shared-libraries) mentions this error and provides another solution with the following commands.

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```